# finding the local extremum of a function of 2 variables

Tags: functions

consider the function with 2 variables $f(x,y)=-2(x-y)^2+x^4+y^4$
(n.b.: f is from R^2 onto R).
I proved that it has 2 local minimums other than f(0,0)
but how can i prove that f(0,0) is a local extremum??

I am using the method that says let $g(x,y)=f_{xx}(x,y)$. $f_{yy}(x,y)-(f_{xy}(x,y))^2$ and which indicates that if $g(a,b)>0$ and ( $f_{xx}(a,b)>0$ or $f_{xx}(a,b)<0$ ) then f(a,b) is a local extremum of f
please solve according to this method if you can 
otherwise just solve it any way possible

Answer (score 0):

The origin is not a local extremum, it's a saddle point. First look along the line $x=y$. Clearly, the origin is a local minimum along this line. Now look along the line $x=-y$. For small values, the quadratic dominates the forth order terms, so your function initially swings negative, and thus along this line the origin is a local maximum.